# Cassandra upgrade from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I recently upgraded my node from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0. But the node was not able to find the keyspaces which was there before. I had run nodetool -a upgradesstables before upgrading to 2.1.0. I had also run nodetool drain before shutting down previous version.

I'm runnig this node on windows. Now nodetool status only shows 58.94 KB load. Te load was aroung 1.5 GB in the old version.

```
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  58.94 KB   256     100.0%            e10e77e8-79d0-4a54-bb1f-a36944f3c3a6  rack1
```

I can see my keyspace directory in the data directory but its not being picked up by 2.1.0. Any recommendations on what I should be checking?. I don't see any mention of the missing keyspace in the startup log or the system log.

UPDATE

Cassandra yaml specs from 2.1.0 and above has the configs for data, commitlog and saved cache commented out by default. I just updated the directory without seeing the "#" in the yaml file.

Comment: Are you sure you're pointing to the right data directory?

Comment: @JonHaddad Yes. The new cassandra yaml comments all the  directory specs by default!